# Android - project defaulting to appCompat library project's resources for layout

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat

I've added the appCompat supporting library to my project using instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res)  (adding library with resources using Eclipse).  When trying to reference a layout, it defaults to the appCompat project res/layout folder, not the one in the current project:
[image]

Is there a step I missed in designating the current project's resources as the default?  Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working now.  Had to rebuild the project.